# How to remove asp.net identity management database tables?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

In my asp.net core application, the user is required to log in using Google OAuth. This part is working fine using VS2017 generated code and by enabling Google authentication.

The problem I have is that, by default, the application creates a bunch of database tables related to asp.net users and roles. I really don't need to save any information in these tables. All I care for is email and name, and I am getting both these values through OAuth.

How can I disable ASP.NET's own identity management entirely?

The default generated code defines a method `ExternalLoginCallback` for `AccountController` class. The relevant lines are:

```
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAysnc(...);
return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
```

I am guessing I need to get rid of the second line. Is this correct?

Finally, I still need an instance of `ApplicationUser` that I should be able to access from any part of the code. Do I store it in a session object or is there a better way? Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need those tables, you probably should not use ASP.NET Core Identity. Instead, you can use the standalone Cookie Authentication, which can save user's email and name in cookie. read the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x) for more detail.

Here is something I got from docs. I have not tried this. Let me know if you have trouble on this.

Invoke the `UseAuthentication` method in the Configure method of the `Startup.cs` file:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Invoke the `AddXxx` methods in the `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup.cs` file:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options => {
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Forbidden/";
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Unauthorized/";
    })
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>{
        googleOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
        googleOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    });
```

[Here](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/blob/experimental/samples/Mvc.Client/Startup.cs) is another working example.

After user logged in, you can always get user's information from `HttpContext.User.Claims` without an instance of `ApplicationUser`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. However, it looks like there is something needed between the calls to _signInManager.GetExternalLoginAsync and _signInManager,ExternalLoginSignInAsync. Otherwise, the second call fails. Previously, there were two calls in between - _userManager.CreateAsync and _userManager.AddLoginAsync. Regards.

Comment: @Peter If you use standalone Cookie Authentication, you should not use the signInManager or userManager since they are part of ASP.NET Core Identity. You can refer to [this project](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/tree/experimental/samples/Mvc.Client) to see how to get desired information.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Our requirement is that the user has to be authenticated using Google oAuth. Is there any simpler way to run oAuth without using siginManager calls? Thanks.

Comment: @Peter `return Challenge("Google");` from your controller should redirect user to Google login page. You can check `User.Identity.IsAuthencated` to tell whether the user has logged in.